# RESTkit Code 1001 could not find object for keyPath: "'"

Tags: ios4, xcode4.2, restkit

Thanks in advance for all your help community!!  i had a early problem which was pointed out to me and i fixed "[Person object]-should be-->[Person alloc]init]i fixed that and  now able to add a Person object now to my server. But here is the problem all the values on server are null and its throwing back a 1001 code Code=1001 "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''" UserInfo=0x5938ce0 {=RKObjectMapperKeyPath, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''}
what am i mapping wrong any ideas? Noobie here and be grateful for any help provided!
Ohh yea am willing to pay for lessons on this matter if your in socal. Thnx again!

```
RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class]];
 [userMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"personId"];

RKObjectMapping* dogMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Dog class]];
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"person_id" toAttribute:@"spersonId"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"dogId"]; 

RKObjectMapping *dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]]; 
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"dog" toAttribute:@"dogs"]; 
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"person" toRelationship:@"person" withMapping:userMapping]; 
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:dataMapping]; 

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping 
forKeyPath:@"people"];

RKObjectRouter * router = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router;
[router routeClass: [Person class] toResourcePath:@"/people/:personId"];
[router routeClass: [Person class] toResourcePath:@"/people" 
forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

RKObjectMapping *personSerializationMapping= [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:
[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[personSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"name", nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider 
setSerializationMapping:personSerializationMapping forClass: [Person class]];

Person* daveLiu =[[[Person alloc]init]autorelease];
daveLiu.name = @"dave";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:daveLiu  delegate:self];
```

Comment: Are you trying to post to server or read from server?

Answer (score 1):

All of my objects from my server are "anonymous" and I had this same problem with RestKit not being able to find the correct mapping.  The way I fixed it was to use the objectManager methods that let me include the mapping:

```
[objectManager postObject:object mapResponseWith:[object objectMapping] delegate:self];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:path objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
```

So now my contracts that all come from the server like this:

```
{
    "Id": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab",
    "Type": "SURVEY",
    "Code": "1234",
    "Description": "blah blah blah",
    "Message": "blah blah blah",
    "Url": "http://nowhere.com/",
    "NextAttemptHours": 4
}
```

Can be mapped into the correct object.  It's a bit of extra work to keep you object mappings available, but it does the job.  I did it by implementing a class method on my objects to return the appropriate objectMapping which keeps things very clean and understandable.